# Split data & combine 1 column in query

Tags: sql

Can I combine data from data (variable) and 1 column in different table?

Example:

Table 1 (1 rows)
Fieldname : Name, Hobby, address

```
Value     : John | Learn | India <value>
```

Table 2 (3 rows)
FieldName: Code

```
Value    :01
Value    :02
Value    :03
```

I want result query this:

Fieldname:Code, Datavalue

```
Value    :01 | John
Value    :02 | Learn
Value    :03 | India
```

Can I combine that data?
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you have match values between two tables

Eg if you have as below you can convert.
Fieldname : Name, Hobby, address,col1,col2,col3
Value : John | Learn | India|01|02|03